# How can I cat some continous logs and grep word in real time?

Tags: linux

In Linux, I want to monitor the output of some tool, e.g. dbus-monitor's output. I hope to cat some special key word of its output, and then use the key word to be as input argument of other program. Like below, but it is not good.

```
dbus-monitor --system > d.log &
var=`cat d.log | grep some-key-word`
my_script.sh $var
```

I hope to monitor the output flow in real time, and not to cat the whole log from beginning. Just to cat its latest change. E.g. dmesg provides an option, dmesg -w, which meets what I want.

```
 -w, --follow                wait for new messages
```

So how to make such script? To cat the latest new output and use it continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cat`, use `tail -F <file> | grep <something>`. This option makes tail to wait for and output all incoming data. Most likely, you also will need to modify buffering mode for standard streams with `stdbuf -oL` (by default, `stdout` is fully buffered meaning that data is written into file each couple of kilobytes and *not* after each line).